# PHP mt_rand() in a JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I made a code for a moving text in a mask.
A tried to change the text randomly but after one change...the script works, but the text remains the same. The mt_rand() function works just once.
What is the problem in this script?!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        <?php
        $rid = mt_rand(1,10);
        echo "$(\"#moving_fact\").text(\"".$rowf[$rid]["fact"]."\");"; 
        ?>
        var pos=$("#moving_fact").position();
        var width=$("#moving_fact").width() + 50;
        pos.left= 800;
        $("#moving_fact").css({left: pos.left});

    setInterval(function() {
        if (width + pos.left > 0) {
            pos.left= pos.left - 1;
            $("#moving_fact").css({left: pos.left});
        } else {
            pos.left = 800;
            $("#moving_fact").css({left: pos.left});
            width = $("#moving_fact").width() + 50;
            <?php
            $rid = mt_rand(1,10);
            echo "$(\"#moving_fact\").text(\"". $rowf[$rid]["fact"] ."\")";
            ?>
        }
    },10);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `PHP` to execute with `JavaScript` directly! `PHP` is server-side and `JavaScript` is client-side.

In that case just use `JavaScript` to generate random value.

Comment: But my text is in a database.

Comment: @CatalinStanciu then use `AJAX` to fetch that data.

Comment: but if i use in jquery something like load()...is it ok? or it's not optimal?

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` is server side and `javascript` is client side so you cannot use PHP  function in javascript You have to use javascript function `Math.random()`.

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```